# I've already installed kernel-devel on centos, still cannot find kernel header

Tags: c, linux, file, header

I've already installed kernel-devel on centos, still cannot find kernel header

```
# yum install kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors....net
 * extras: ...
 * updates: mirrors.....net
Package kernel-devel-2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

But still the header files are not found by gcc:

```
# cat testkmem.c
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/kmem.h>
int main(){

    return 0;
}

# gcc testkmem.c
testkmem.c:2:21: error: sys/kmem.h: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this compilation issue, any extra yum packages that are needed?

Comment: Kernel headers is for **kernel** drivers, not for user space programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know locate command?

```
$ locate kmem.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64/include/config/memcg/kmem.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64/include/trace/events/kmem.h
```

:-), I think your **PATH** has error.